# timer bugs can't clear in react-hooks with useRef

Tags: reactjs

I'am tring to build a number-reaseing animation in a component ,and i use useRef to save my timer,and use a state to show the number changes .So the number absolutly changed ,but it can worked also after the number passed the number i set as 100;I checked the timer-ID and it didn't be changed,but the timer-clear didn't work.This is my code;

```js
import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  num: number
}

const AnimateP: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const numAdd = useCallback(() => {
    const temp = num;
    setNum(temp + 1)
    if(temp>props.num) {
      console.log("clearTimeout",_timer.current)
      console.log(_timer,"_timer")
      clearTimeout(_timer.current)
    }
  }, [num])
  
  const _timer = useRef<NodeJS.Timer>(
    setTimeout(() => {
      numAdd()
    }, 100)
  )



  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#000", color: "#fff" }}>{num}</div>
  )
}

export default AnimateP;[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useRef don't support lazy initianization. You passed in `setTimeout()` as parammeter. It will be called at every rendering. You will set many timeout, but only last one will modify your `num`. Your clearTimeout can only delete the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid running any code with side-effects inside of callback function passed to `useRef`. Instead, use `useEffect` to start the loop, and then fire your function recursively from within itself:

```
import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface Props {
    num: number;
}

const AnimateP: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

    const numAdd = useCallback(() => {
        const temp = num;
        setNum(temp + 1);
        if (temp > props.num) {
            console.log("break the loop of recursion");
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(numAdd, 100);
    }, [props.num, num]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(numAdd, 100);
    }, [numAdd]);

    return <div style={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#000", color: "#fff" }}>{num}</div>;
};
```